# extract and convert any ascii code from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

How can I extract the ascii code from a string and then convert it to char?

`string = "a &#8211; b"`

to

`a – b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CGI](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html) library from ruby

```
CGI.unescapeHTML("a &#8211; b")
#=> "a – b"
```